# Playing Hi-Res audio files on mac with M-audio Revolution 5.1

Tags: music, audio

I have audio file with 192Khz/24bit sound, and Revo 5.1 and driver for Snow Leopard. This driver is not official, and it is only the kext, without any GUI, and I can't see sound quality playing right now. I just set up in Audio Midi Setup App sound format of 192Khz. How can I see be sure the sound playing in 192/24 quality, not just 192/16? Is 24bit/16bit sound switching begins automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I used to own one of these cards and used it on a Windows PC. If I'm not mistaken, M-Audio (now owned by Avid) no longer supports this card. It's been declared obsolete and orphaned. Good luck.

Comment: This is unrelated to this question, but I wanted you to see this: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/618/tag-wikis-should-not-contain-questions-about

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. You have brought something to my attention that I was not aware of. Please see my response at the link above.